# How to change frame's background color in code behind?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am creating an app for android, iOS and WP using xamarin. in one of my pages, i have a `frame` inside a `datatemplate`and i can't acess frame element in code behind, so i bind backgroundcolor of frame to a variable. And when user clicks on a button, the color should change but it does not.

XAML :

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView">
   <CollectionView.EmptyView>
      <Label Text="Não foram encontrados contactos com email" x:Name="SemContactos" IsVisible="False"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,100,100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>
   </CollectionView.EmptyView>
   <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
      <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2"/>
   </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Name="template">
         <Grid Padding="5" x:Name="grid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Frame BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource myResourceKey}"
               OutlineColor="LightGray"
               CornerRadius="3" Padding="0.5" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" x:Name="frameContacto">
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
               <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ContactoSelecionado" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <StackLayout  Spacing="5">
               <Image  x:Name="imageX" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                  Source="{Binding Foto}"
                  Aspect="AspectFill"
                  HeightRequest="60"
                  WidthRequest="60"
                  HorizontalOptions="Center" />
               <!--Source="{local:ImageResource KiaiDay.Images.user.png}"-->
               <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Nome}" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="Black"/>
               <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Email}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
<StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,1,.5,.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="butoes" IsVisible="False">
   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
      <Button Text="Seleccionar todos" WidthRequest="170" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#1E90FF" FontAttributes="Bold" CornerRadius="2" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="SeleccionarTodos" x:Name="selTodos"/>
      <Button Text="Convidar" WidthRequest="170" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#1E90FF" FontAttributes="Bold" CornerRadius="2" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
   </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

And C#

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

public partial class ConviteEmailPage: ContentPage {

    Color corFrame = Color.White;

    public ConviteEmailPage() {
        this.Resources.Add("myResourceKey", corFrame);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SeleccionarTodos(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (selTodos.Text == "Desmarcar") selTodos.Text = "Seleccionar Todos";
        else selTodos.Text = "Desmarcar";
        corFrame = Color.LightGray;

    }
```

Comment: You can bind color to model, it will be changed by model data.

Comment: Is it your aim to change the background color of all frames or only the one you've clicked? Your attempt is through using a DynamicResource, but all frames look at the same DynamicResource so this way all of them will change background if the dynamic resource changes. In your example if you want the DynamicResource to be updated you could change `corFrame = Color.LightGray` to `this.Resources["myResourceKey"] = Color.LightGray`. Right now you only change the value of the `corFrame` field and not the `this.Resources` entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code , Frame's color is in `CollectionView.ItemTemplate`.If want to change color in Item, you should change model's data ,not directly change by binded Resource name or x:Name to do that.

In model add `MyColor` property to model `Monkey`:

```
private string mycolor = "Accent";

public string MyColor
{
   get
   {
      return mycolor;
   }
   set
   {
      if (mycolor != value)
      {
          mycolor = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("MyColor");
      }
    }
 }
```

If want be changeg dynamiclly , also need `INotifyPropertyChanged` to model:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then bind `MyColor` in **Xaml** :

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <CollectionViewDemos:StringToColorConverter x:Key="StringToColorConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

Frame BackgroundColor="{Binding MyColor, Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter}}"
```

It also need `IValueConverter` to convert color from string:

```
public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        string valueAsString = value.ToString();
        switch (valueAsString)
        {
            case ("Red"):
                {
                    return Color.Red;
                }
            case ("Accent"):
                {
                    return Color.Accent;
                }
            default:
                {
                    return Color.FromHex(value.ToString());
                }
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Last , you can test when CollectionView `SelectedItem`

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonkey, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Adding `selectedMonkey` to `MonkeyList` model. When selected, changed color to red as follow:

```
Monkey selectedMonkey;
public Monkey SelectedMonkey
{
    get
    {
        return selectedMonkey;
    }
    set
    {
        if (selectedMonkey != value)
        {
            selectedMonkey.MyTextColor = "Red"; //Here is changing the color
            selectedMonkey = value;
        }
    }
}
```